# Multiple views/renders of the same kineticjs model

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am building a graph utility that displays a rather large graph containing a lot of data. 
One of the things I would like to be able to support is having multiple views of the data simultaneously in different panels of my application.

I've drawn a picture to try and demonstrate what i mean. Suppose i've built the gradiented image in the background using kinetic.

[image: Imgur]

I'd like to be able to grab show the part outlined in red and the part outlined in green simultaneously, without having to rebuild the entire image.

[image: Imgur]

```
var stage1 = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container1',
  width: somewidth,
  height: someheight
});

var stage2 = new Kinetic.Stage({
  container: 'container1',
  width: someotherwidth,
  height: someotherheight
});

var Layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer({
  y: someY,
  scale: someScale
});
// add stuff to first layer here...

var Layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer({
  y: otherY,
  scale: otherScale
});
// add other stuff to second layer here...

stage1.add(mapLayer);
stage1.add(topLayer);

stage2.add(mapLayer);
stage2.add(topLayer);
```

at the point at which I've added my layers to stage1, everything is fine, but as soon as i try to add them to stage2 as well, it breaks down. I'm sifting through the source but I cant see anything forcing data to be unique to a stage. Is this possible? Or do i have to duplicate all of my shapes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a node into multiple parents is not possible by KineticJS design. Each `Layer` has `<canvas>` element. As I know it is not possible to insert a DOM element into document twice.